# Ubuntu 17.04 freezes randomly after recent update

Tags: updates, 17.04

I recently updated my Ubuntu using Software Update tool. After the recent update, Ubuntu is freezing randomly, also it is taking a long time to boot up.

```
**Machine Info:** 
Processor: Intel i3 
Memory: 6 GB
Recent Kernal Version: 4.10.0-35-generic
```

Anyone has any idea why this might be. And solution for this issue. Thanks

Comment: Graphics card/chipset?

Comment: Show me `sudo lsblk` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/crypttab`. Copy/paste that output into your original question please, not into the comments. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info and I'll take a look for you.